# Colab variable inspector stops working after importing from fastbook

Tags: colab, fastai

As best as I could find, this question was not asked before.
I'm using colab, and I use its variable inspector.
I'm trying to do the FastAI exercices, and I noticed that when doing them, the variable inspector stops showing variables.
For instance - I open a new notebook and I start creating variables in cells. x=5, a=6 and so forth. These variables are shown in the inspector.
But, once I run the line:

```
from fastbook import *
```

the variable inspector gets wiped clean, and stops showing variables, even when I create new variables.

I'd appreciate any help. Thank!

Answer (score 0):

It was explained to me that the issue here is that when * is imported from fastbook, it floods the inspector with everything that is inside fastbook.
The better way to import would be:

`import fastbook as fb`

I tested it and it actually works!